# How to use icontains in a key value of a DictField in Django queryset?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Given the following model:

```
class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    others = DictField()
```

And the following code:

```
bahia = Team()
bahia.name = "E.C. Bahia"
bahia.others = {"title": "Ninguém nos Vence em Vibração!!!"}
bahia.save()

vicetoria = Team()
vicetoria.name = "E.C. Vicetoria"
vicetoria.others = {"title": "Vice de tudo!"}
vicetoria.save()
```

I want to find the object that have the word **vence**, (case insensitive) contained in **title** value of the field **others**.

I tried something like:

```
teams = Team.objects.filter(others__title__icontains="vence")
```

that gives me the following error:

```
FieldError: Join on field 'others' not permitted. Did you misspell 'title' for the lookup type?
```

I also already tried:

```
teams = Team.objects.filter(others__icontains={"title":"vence"})
```

that returns None and I know there is at least one collection as result.

**SOLUTION:**

```
teams = Team.objects.raw_query({"others.title": {"$regex" : "vence", "$options": "i"}})
```

The **i** option makes the search insensitive.

Comment: Where are you getting DictField from? Are you trying to use a serialiser field from django rest framework in a Model object?

Comment: I created the DictField. It's being saved normally in the database. I am using MongoDB.

Comment: Can you show me what your DictField() looks like?

Comment: Hey, @Asher! It's there. In the example. bahia.others and vicetoria.others are the DictFields

Comment: I understand your example. I suspect that the issue your having is to do with using a custom model field in your models. What I'm wondering is what the DictField class looks like? How have you created your own field class? Are you inheriting from another class?

Comment: Ah! Ok. It's not another class. It's a field that varies. Each object can have its own dict with different keys from each other.

Comment: Can you show me your import statements from the top of your models.py file?

Comment: For sure: from djangotoolbox.fields import ListField, EmbeddedModelField, DictField

Answer (score 0):

I believe (correct me if I'm wrong) that djangotoolbox DictField doesn't support icontain.

To filter the Dict Field you need to do something like:

`Team.objects.raw_query({'title': { $regex : /vence/i } })`

Check out this answer: [How do I filter based on dict contents in a DictField on a model using the Django-MongoDB Engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629661/how-do-i-filter-based-on-dict-contents-in-a-dictfield-on-a-model-using-the-djang)

This answer shows how to do case insensitive mongodb queries: [How do I make case-insensitive queries on Mongodb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7101703/how-do-i-make-case-insensitive-queries-on-mongodb)

Comment: The problem here, is that I need the objects which the field **contains** the word **vence** or **Vence** or **vEnce**

Comment: Updated. Have a look at the answer I linked. There are lots of ways to do mongodb case insensitive queries.

Comment: Didn't work for me. I'll past the solutionin the question. Thanks for your help!